# resetting state of app when user logs out

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to write a logout function in my iOS app that uses coreData. When a user logs out, everything should get deleted, and they should be presented with the login screen. Then when a new user logs in, the experience should be completely fresh, as if the user deleted the app and reinstalled it.

My approach has been to delete the user (there is only ever one), and put cascade relationships on all the models, so a `user has_one program` which `has_many days` when I save the context on the user, all the child objects should also be deleted, right?

Here is my method:

```
- (void)LogUserOut
{
    [self.context deleteObject:self.currentUser];

    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [self.context save:&saveError];

    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
}
```

The problem is that the child objects aren't being deleted. Am I missing something here?

Edit: I just checked with `childObject.isDeleted?` and got back false, so the cascade option absolutely isn't working.

Edit 2:

Here is a screenshot of the coredata entity:
[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of your data model showing the cascade delete rule. That should be all you need, if it's configured properly.

Comment: I've sort of solved the problem by overwriting `prepareForDeletion` in the managedObject Subclass, but I'll post the screenshot.

Comment: I would like to understand why cascade isn't working.

Comment: One possible explanation is that your user or your context is `nil` and that you are not actually deleting it.

Comment: I'm definitely deleting it. If I overwrite `prepareForDeletion`, the code is called, or if I just call isDeleted it returns true